# Sequential to-do list using GitHub issues

Tags: github

At my company we are using GitHub issues to track issues, bugs, tasks, etc. We have tags for priorities but that is not working really well. What we would like to do is to build a list of tasks that has an order and the order is the order in which things will get done.

Is there any way of doing this with GitHub?

Comment: We ended up moving to Jira :(

Answer (score 2):

My team ran into similar problems: a bug tracking system is great for logging all bugs and new functionality to be built, but we needed something more to help us prioritize and work together. The process we developed and that works really well for us is a combination of a bug tracker (BugZilla in our case) and Trello. Trello is a superb piece of web software to keep track of various lists, and it is free.

We use it as follows:

- a list per category (for instance, back-end, front-end, etc.)
- in addition to the category lists the following lists: Doing, Testing, Done
- different colors to indicate the priority of issues per category

This allows us to have different priority lists which more closely reflects reality for us. Also, it is very easy to see who is working on what.

In addition to the above process, we also use Trello exclusively (i.e. without a bugtracking system) for quick and dirty projects to keep the overhead of adding new tasks low.

Comment: This isn't a good answer. The question is asking *how* to compile a certain list of *GitHub issues*. Instead, your answer is a *subjective recommendation* of BugZilla and Trello, as well as examples of how the lists could be structured. Your post doesn't even *mention* GitHub. Please improve or delete this answer.

Comment: @amon, I disagree. Pablo specifically mentions *GitHub or other tool* in the question. My recommendation is indeed 'subjective'; what is an 'objective recommendation'? I have modified my answer to state more explicitly what I am answering.

Comment: @amon I have to agree with Mauritz here, it does mention whether another tool could be used on top of Github to accomplish this.

Comment: @amon, btw: why was this migrated from 'Programmers' to 'Web Applications'? This question has to do with programming processes and not with web development.

Comment: @MauritzHansen Pablo specifically mentions “*GitHub or some other tool on top the the GitHub issues*” in the question. Your answer does not indicate how Trello or BugZilla could be integrated with GH issues. Regarding the migration: [programmers.se] is about conceptual software development questions like workflows, whereas Web Apps is [about] the *usage* of web applications – it has nothing to do with web development. See also [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6312)